# Google sheets query from pivot table

Tags: sql, google-sheets, pivot-table

I have an exercise tracking sheet where raw data is put into a pivot table and further refined through query. The query, courtesy of EdNelson (thank you!) might need a little tweak however. Here's the query: `=UNIQUE(query(Suoritusanalyysi!$D2:$K, ʺSELECT D,Max(F),Max(G),Max(H),Max(I),Max(J),Max(K),Avg(F),Avg(G),Avg(H),Avg(I),Avg(K),Sum(F),Sum(K),Count(F) Where D !='' Group By D Label Max(F) 'Max vol.', Max(G) 'Max tih.', Max(H) 'Max int.', Max(I) 'Max sarja', Max(J) 'Max km. int.', Max(K) 'Max toistot', Avg(F) 'Km. vol.', Avg(G) 'Km. tih.', Avg(H) 'Km. int.', Avg(I) 'Km. sarja', Avg(K) 'Km. toistot', Sum(F) 'Total vol.', Sum(K) 'Total toistot', Count(F) 'Kerrat'ʺ))`

The problem is that move "P KB" in A6 of sheet "Liikekoonti" is actually only one of the two such moves (one listing per arm for single-arm moves) listed in the pivot table in Suoritusanalyysi!D10:D11. Query takes labels from D, but since pivot table didn't list another "P KB", query can't find the values for the other arm. How do I get query to include both "o" and "v" of Suoritusanalyysi!E for an exercise or the pivot table to list "P KB" for both "o" and "v"?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1if_-fdH_roKZVtNskjrZBWALNe6f3E2d0modjKNNVp8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @kuura it is Ed again. I suggest trying adding P KBo and P KBv to The valid list Likkeet. Then add them to your PT. Select them on Treenidata under Liike instead of P KB. It will then have both on you PT. Note they will both have red font based on there own max value.

Comment: Hello @Ed Nelson, that would be one way of doing it, and actually wouldn't be that large of a task; a simple copy-paste and search and replace would do it. I found another way of getting rid of the problem of it not counting the volume of both P KB: in Suoritusanalyysi PT, I switched columns D and E and made the appropriate changes to the query, and now it lists both P KB separately. However, the only way to track both left and right-handed moves' values would be through adding them to the valid list, as you suggested. I think this one is solved. Thank you again!